# How Set checks for duplicates? Java HashSet

Tags: java, set, hashset

For the below code it outputs " 1 ". and second code outputs " 2 " I don't understand why this is happening. Is it because I am adding the same object? How should I achieve the desired output 2.

```
import java.util.*;
public class maptest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer[]> set = new HashSet<Integer[]>();
    Integer[] t = new Integer[2];
    t[0] = t[1] = 1;
    set.add(t);
    Integer[] t1 = new Integer[2];
    t[0] = t[1] = 0;
    set.add(t);
    System.out.println(set.size());

   }
}
```

Second Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class maptest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer[]> set = new HashSet<Integer[]>();
    Integer[] t = new Integer[2];
    t[0] = t[1] = 1;
    set.add(t);
    Integer[] t1 = new Integer[2];
    t1[0] = t1[1] = 1;
    set.add(t1);
    System.out.println(set.size());

    }
}
```

Comment: You're only adding one `Object` to the `Set`. The fact that you change its contents is irrelevant

Comment: So how should I achieve the desired output? Adding a new object with the same value also creates two new entry.

Comment: You're using a `Set`. Adding an object two times will not work. The second `add` will return `false`. Thus you haven't add `t` once more to the `Set`.

Comment: Yup, as seen at your code. try this `set.add(t1);`

Comment: Why are you creating the t1 instance when you're not using it?

Comment: But to answer you answer quick: A `HashSet` uses `equals` and `hashCode` to evaluate equality.

Comment: @LiCio how should I achieve the desired output?

Comment: The answers explain it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Set` implementation probably calls `t.hashCode()` and since arrays don't override the [`Object.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) method, the same object will have the same hashcode. Changing the array's contents thus does not affect its hash code. To get an array's hash code correctly, you should call [`Arrays.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode(int[])).

You shouldn't really put mutable things inside sets anyways, so I would suggest you put immutable lists into sets instead. If you want to stick with arrays, just create a new array, like you did with `t1`, and put it into the set.

EDIT:

For code 2, `t` and `t1` are two different arrays so their hash code are different. Again, since the `hashCode` method is not overridden in arrays. The array's contents don't effect the hash code, whether or not they are the same.

Comment: I did that in the second code but set size becomes 2. Same values in both objects. I tried with int[] also. It has the same behavior.

Comment: @Vivek `t.hashCode()` returns a value that has nothing to do with what's inside the array. It just returns the memory address (which is what the default hash code implementation does).

Comment: @Vivek Code 2 prints 2 because there are two _different_ array objects in the set. Whenever you use `new`, you are creating a new object. In code 1, you added `t` to the set, then you added the same `t` to the set again. The second addition is thus ignored. `t` has different contents the second time, but that is not reflected in its hash code, so the set ignores the second addition.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the `Object` to a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which

> contains no duplicate elements.

You are only ever adding one `Object` to the `Set`. You only change the value of it's contents. To see what I mean try adding `System.out.println(set.add(t));`.

As the [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) method:

> Returns true if this set did not already contain the specified element

Also your `t1` is completely irrelevant in your first code snippet as you never use it.

---

In your second code snippet it outputs two because you are adding two *different* `Integer[]` `Objects` to the `Set`

Try printing out the hashcode of the `Objects` to see how this works:

```
Integer[] t = new Integer[2];
t[0] = t[1] = 1;
//Before we change the values
System.out.println(t.hashCode());
Integer[] t1 = new Integer[2];
t1[0] = t1[1] = 1;
//After we change the values of t
System.out.println(t.hashCode());
//Hashcode of the second object
System.out.println(t1.hashCode());
```

Output:

```
//Hashcode for t is the same before and after modifying data
366712642
366712642
//Hashcode for t1 is different from t; different object
1829164700
```

Comment: can you please explain what's happening with code 2?

Answer (score 2):

A `Set` contains only distinct element (it is its nature). The basic implementation, `HashSet`, use `hashCode()` to first find a bucket containing values then `equals(Object)` to look for a distinct value.

Arrays are simple: their hashCode() use the default, inherited from `Object`, and therefore depending on reference. The `equals(Object)` is also the same than `Object`: it check only the identify, that is: references must be equals.

Defined as Java:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
  return other == this;
}
```

If you want to put distinct arrays, you'll have to either try your luck with `TreeSet` and a proper implementation of `Comparator`, either wrap you array or use a `List` or another `Set`:

```
Set<List<Integer[]>> set = new HashSet<>();
Integer[] t = new Integer[]{1, 1};
set.add(Arrays.asList(t));
Integer[] t1 = new Integer[]{1, 1};
set.add(Arrays.asList(t1));
System.out.println(set.size());
```

As for mutability of the object used in a `Set` or a `Map` key:

- fields used by the `boolean equals(Object)` should not be muted because the muted object could be then equals to another. The Set would no longer contains distinct values.
- fields used by the `int hashCode()` should not be muted for hash based collection (`HashSet`, `HashMap`) because as said above their operate by putting items in a bucket. If the hashCode() change, it is likely the place of the object in the bucket will also change: the `Set` would then contains twice the same reference.
- fields used by the `int compareTo(T)` or `Comparator::compare(T,T)` should not be muted for the same reason than `equals`: the `SortedSet` would not know there was a change.

If the need arise, you would have to first remove item from the set, then mutate it, the re-add it.

Answer (score 1):

How `java.util.Set` implementations *check* for duplicate objects depends on the implementation, but per the documentation of `Set`, the appropriate meaning of "duplicate" is that `o1.equals(o2)`.

Since `HashSet` in particular is based on a hash table, it will go about looking for a duplicate by computing the `hashCode()` of the object presented to it, and then going through all the objects, if any, in the corresponding hash bucket.

Arrays do not override `hashCode()` or `equals()`, so they implement instance identity, not value identity.  Thus, regardless of the values of its elements, a given array always has the same hash code, and always `equals()` itself and only itself.  You first code adds the same array object to a set two times.  Regardless of the values of its elements, it is still the same set.  The second code adds two different array objects to a set.  Regardless of the values of their elements, they are different objects.

Note, too, that if you have mutable objects that implement value identity, such that their equality and hash codes depends on the values of their members, then modifying such an object while it is a member of a `Set` very likely breaks the `Set`.  This is documented on a per-implementation basis.