# Query returning a lot of repeated records

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I try to make query from two tables (Statement, AppCurContract), but receive a lot of repeated records. Even if I make query only from Statement, I receive the same result.
It started when I added appCurContracts field to the Statement bean.

I found same question here [Spring Data JPA query return repeated row instead of actual data, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53281870/spring-data-jpa-query-return-repeated-row-instead-of-actual-data-why)

But I have unique key in both tables. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Entity
@Table
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "appCurContracts")
public class Statement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String numStatement;
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime dateTimeSubmStatement;
    private int filialId;
    private int myself;
    private int status;
    private Date modifyDate;
    private String nameNonResident;
    private String email;
    private Integer typeStatement;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "statement", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AppCurContract> appCurContracts;
    public Statement() {
        super();
    }

    public Statement(String nameDocument, String numStatement, LocalDateTime dateTimeSubmStatement, String jurPerson, String iin_bin, int filialId, int myself, int status, Date modifyDate, String nameNonResident, String contractNum, Date contractDate, String phone, String email, Integer typeStatement, String json, String iinBinRight, AppCurContract... appCurContracts) {
        this.numStatement = numStatement;
        this.dateTimeSubmStatement = dateTimeSubmStatement;
        this.filialId = filialId;
        this.myself = myself;
        this.status = status;
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
        this.nameNonResident = nameNonResident;
        this.email = email;
        this.typeStatement = typeStatement;
        this.appCurContracts = Stream.of(appCurContracts).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.appCurContracts.forEach(x -> x.setStatement(this));
    }

    public void setAppCurContracts(Set<AppCurContract> appCurContracts) {

        for (AppCurContract child : appCurContracts) {

            child.setStatement(this);
        }
        this.appCurContracts = appCurContracts;
    }
}
```

```
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
public class AppCurContract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn()
    private Statement statement;
    private String jurPerson;
    private String iin_bin;
    private String nameDocument;
    private String contractNum;
    private String contractDate;

    public AppCurContract() {
        super();
    }

    public AppCurContract(String jurPerson, String iin_bin, String nameDocument, String contractNum, String contractDate) {
        this.jurPerson = jurPerson;
        this.iin_bin = iin_bin;
        this.nameDocument = nameDocument;
        this.contractNum = contractNum;
        this.contractDate = contractDate;
    }
}
```

```
public interface StatementRepo extends JpaRepository<Statement, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT d FROM Statement d JOIN d.appCurContracts e" +
            " WHERE d.status = ?1")

//    @Query("SELECT d FROM Statement d WHERE d.status = ?1")

    List<Statement> findByStatus(Integer status);

    List<Statement> findStatementsByEmailEquals(String email);
}
```

**EDIT**
Looking carefully at the JSON result I discovered that the result is not just repeated, but the field "appCurontract" contains nested statements then again "appCurContract" (nested in each other), etc. I think so indefinitely. 
I expect only 5 records.

Comment: What is the purpose of "JOIN d.appCurContracts e" ?

Comment: *Looking carefully at the JSON result I discovered that the result is not just repeated, but the field "appCurontract" contains nested statements then again "appCurContract" (nested in each other), etc. I think so indefinitely*. So what exactly is the issue you face. The JSON is not as you expect or the data loaded from the database is not as you expect because these are 2 completely different things.

Comment: data loaded from the database is not as I expect

Answer (score 0):

Define the hashcode method yourself, with whatever condition necessary as [set uses this to check for duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52339684/783412). Your code (in your repository implementation) will then become:

```
List<Statement> findDistinctByEmail(String email);
```

And you should not need the Query annotation.

Comment: I added hashcode method to Statement with all fields except appCurContracts. But same result.

Comment: I see no difference in your post, can you please mark edits using an **EDIT** moniker?

Comment: Just at the end of post. Marked as EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *setAppCurContracts* method on Statement class. Is not necessary.

Remove the @Query's annotation and use the *findByStatus* method.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. I added **@JsonIgnore** annotation to the Statement field in AppCurContract class.

```
public class AppCurContract {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn()
private Statement statement;
private String jurPerson;
private String iin_bin;
private String nameDocument;
private String contractNum;
private String contractDate;
```

Thank you all for participating